# Convert date string in format 'dd-mm-yyyy' to string format 'dd mon' using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

I have a date in string format - `'25-03-2020' (dd-mm-yyyy)`. I want to convert it into string format '25 Mar' and display on Frontend. 
How can I achieve this using Javascript?

Comment: Vanilla JS or would *any* JS solution suffice?

Comment: If you want to use library, you can use momentjs for your requirement

Comment: Using Vanilla JS

Comment: Please search before asking. There are thousands of similar questions already.

Comment: Already tried it. Used Date.parse, toISOFormat etc. Don't want to use moment library.